# Get GroupsId from Bot Framework in Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

My question is related to the Bot Framework, with Microsoft Teams. 
The idea is to be able to get the current groupId (if we are not in a 1:1 convesation) to be able to make some Graph request

I tried to get the channel data, with this method

`TeamsChannelData channelData = context.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>()`

But I just have the channel id (Something like `19:b7bce0b2cba1453ca50dd3750ba3bdd7@thread.skype`)

Actually It's not enough to get the GroupId, even with the `/beta` graph endpoint.

Any pointer on how to works with the current group in MS Teams, with a Bot ?

Thx all !

Comment: Is there anything helpful here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/botapis ?

Comment: Hi Sébastien, you are talking about a bot in a conversation, or a bot in a channel of a group?

Comment: But I suspect that in both cases you will not have any relevant information (I already had a look on Conversation, and it's like for Skype: Ids are generated values that cannot be used)

Answer (score 0):

The improvement to include the AAD group id to channel data is still in progress. We are working on it and it is still not released.